# Convert C# List of DateTime to javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui-datepicker, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using mvc5 and i have this model :

```
public class Model
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public IList<DateTime> UnvailableDates { get; set; }
        public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

In view I need to make an array based on UnvailableDates to look like this:
`["2013-03-14","2013-03-15","2013-03-16"]` and to use it on jQuery ui DatePicker but I can't get it to work. 
This is how I did but this is not working :

```
  jQuery(function () {
        var notWorkingArray= '@Model.UnvailableDates';

        var workingArray= ["2013-03-14", "2013-03-15", "2013-03-16"];
        jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                return [workingArray.indexOf(string) == -1];
            }
        });
    });
```

Using **notWorkingArray** to initialize datepicker I will not get disabled dates but if I will use **workingArray** I will get disabled dates that I want.
What I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Were you ever able to convert the List<DateTime> to a JS array? I'm working on something almost identical to this...

Comment: Yes , nut I did something that is not 100% correct. I used hidden fields to hide my full list of dates and the push it to java script array..

Comment: Funny I was about to do the same exact thing. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is because of the toString method of UnvailableDates is not in the right format. You have to use a method to serialize your data to json.

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(aList);
```